# Change color of the focusframe of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, colors, focus, jbutton

I want to change the color of the focus of the JButton, so you know the rectangle that appears if the button is focused.
I know that I can disable the focusing or the painting of the focus with

```
 JButton.setFocusable(false);
 JButton.setFocusPainted(false);
```

But I want the user to be able to focus it and see it. But since I changed the bacckgroundcolor of the button, the somewhat blue focusframe does not look that appealing for the eye (so does the frame which appears if you go over the button with the mouse).
So, in conclusion, what I am looking for is something like

```
JButton.setFocusColor(Color c);
```

I am using Swing of course by the way.

Thank you very much for any answer! Looking forward to it.

Comment: Which look and feel?

Comment: What exactly do you mean @MadProgrammer?

Comment: Swing has a customisable skin api called a “look and feel”, buttons are one of the worst components to try and configure via this api as they tend to ignore many of the usual properties (like background color). “How” you might fix this will depend on which look and feel you’re using

Comment: And on which OS

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much, just read the LookAndFeel article from oracle and it solved my problem [UIManager.setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeel);]. Thank you very much for your quick help, I did not know about the LookAndFeel.